# Can't make very simple regex in RegularExpressionValidator work out

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a very simple regex which I cannot make work on an ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator.
My code is as follows:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revtxtNumeroLiderAnterior" ControlToValidate="txtNumeroLiderAnterior" ErrorMessage="*"
                         ValidationGroup="NumeroLiderAnterior" ValidationExpression="^(\d+)(\s)(-)(\s)" runat="server"
                        CssClass="TextosNaranja" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

When the following string is validated, it doesn't match

```
4 - Mexico Tree
```

I cannot figure out why, I validated in some websites and the expression matches.

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't match the entire string.. all it is matching is the number, the dash, and some spaces. You would need to check individual group matching if that is what you're after (can't remember how to do that with the RegexValidator.

To match the entire thing:

```
^(\d+)(\s)(-)(\s)([\w\s]+)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ capture the words
```